# How to use fowarded ref with material UI component?

Tags: reactjs, ref

Main problem: I get an error in the console that I cannot pass the ref itself to component but by forwarded ref.

Description: I followed instruction on documentation and from forum, but I do not know why I still get an error even if I tried to solved it.

```
   const ReffedInputBase = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    // const inputSearch = useRef();
    return (<StyledInputBase  
    ref={ref}
    value={props.name}
    placeholder="Search…"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
    onChange={({target: {value}}) => {
     props.setName(value)
      props.setOpen(true)
}} />);
  });
  ReffedInputBase.muiName = "StyledInputBase";

<ReffedInputBase
name={name}
  setName={ setName}
  setOpen={ setOpen}
ref={ref}
  />
```

I written inner ref using lowercases because of the fact that  console ordered me it.

It works perfect, but I get red error in console, and it broke apart my deployment..

code from styledInputBase

```
const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
     color: 'inherit',
     '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
       padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
       // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
       paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
       transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
       width: '100%',
       [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
         width: '20ch',
       },
     },
   }));

import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please add code for StyledInputBase component as well ? Also add the errors you get from the console.

Comment: I added in main section